# How to refactor this?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm struggling with a small issue with regard to how I go about refactoring this to a decent pattern.

```
public class DocumentLibrary
{
    private IFileSystem fileSystem;
    private IDocumentLibraryUser user;

    public DocumentLibrary(IDocumentLibraryUser user) : this(user, FileSystemFrom(user)) { }

    public DocumentLibrary(IDocumentLibraryUser user, IFileSystem fileSystem)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }

    public void Create(IWorkerDocument document)
    {
        document.SaveTo(fileSystem);
    }

    public IWorkerDocument AttemptContractRetrieval()
    {
        return new Contract(fileSystem, user);
    }

    public IWorkerDocument AttemptAssignmentRetrieval()
    {
        return new Assignment(fileSystem, user);
    }

    private static IFileSystem FileSystemFrom(IDocumentLibraryUser user)
    {
        var userLibraryDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("/DocLib/" + EnvironmentName() + "/" + user.Id);
        return new FileSystem(userLibraryDirectory);
    }

    private static string EnvironmentName()
    {
        using (var edmxContext = new Entities())
        {
            return (from setting in edmxContext.EnvironmentSettings
                         where setting.Name == "EnvironmentName"
                         select setting.Value).First(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I have two types of worker documents, but I can't seem to easily refactor the two methods above (`AttemptContractRetrieval` and `AttemptAssignmentRetrieval`) to a decent form.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Jim.

Comment: where's the problem? maybe i'm behind the times, but to me refactoring doesn't seem necessary for such a simplistic example.

Comment: The thing is, i will be needing to add more documents shortly, and I don't like the idea of adding this method each time.

Comment: If you are going to be adding more documents, then create a base class to provide these methods. i think it's likely that i'm not understanding the problem. i'll stay tuned to learn something.

Comment: This makes me think of dependency injection frameworks, but I don't understand them well enough to actually know if they are a good idea for this, or how to use them if so.

Comment: Can you share more code about the class these methods are in and how you'd like to call them, maybe this will help us understand...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personnally, I would consider either a factory pattern using factory methods or a builder pattern.

Good use of the factory pattern can be seen in the Enterprise Library solution e.g:
Database.CreateDatabase();
I would say this would be the most straight forward to integrate.

If you chose the Builder pattern, with a requirement to create more complex objects, then you can separate out the creation of complex objects into a series of build commands e.g:
vehicleBuilder.BuildFrame();
vehicleBuilder.BuildEngine();
vehicleBuilder.BuildWheels();
vehicleBuilder.BuildDoors();

Then within these methods, given your chosen implementation, you can add your complexity but make the method calls and construction quite straight forward.

If you haven't come across it, http://www.dofactory.com is a good place to go.

Comment: I'vev used this approach, so I will select this as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two aspects to this:

1. What do I need to do to add a new IWorkerDocument class? Adding new methods seems heavyweight.
2. What code does the caller need in order to create an IWorkerDocument? Right now the responsibility for calling the correct method lies with the caller, hence it's quite likely that the caller also needs to change each time there is a new IWorkerDocument implementor.

The extent of possible refactoring very much depends upon the answer to 2. Sometimes the caller just has to know what they're making, and in which case the code you have is pretty much all you can do. In other cases you have some "WorkerDefinition" stuff, perhaps in the form of a set of Properties, or a name that can be looked up in a registry. In which case the caller wants an api of the form

```
 makeMeAWorker(WorkerDefinition def)
```

on a Factory. Now the caller has no idea what he's asking for, delegates the whole thing to the factory. So the client's world need not change as you add new Worker types.

The Factory can be made extensible by some form of registration scheme or dynamic configuration scheme. We can inject new types into the factory by many different mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what other responsibilities the class has that contains those methods.  Design patterns are structural constructs.  Here we infer that there is a class

```
class Retriever
{
  ...
  public IWorkerDocument AttemptContractRetrieval()
  {
  }

  public IWorkerDocument AttemptAssignmentRetrieval()
  {
  }
}
```

The client code is already deciding whether to call AttemptContractRetrieval(), or AttemptAssignmentRetrieval, so maybe polymorphism is in order.

```
class ContractRetriever
{
   public IWorkerDocument AttemptRetrieval()
   {
   }
}

class AssignmentRetriever
{
   public IWorkerDocument AttemptRetrieval()
   {
   }
}
```

You can make an abstract Retriever class and have these as descendents of that.  This will force the derived classes to have an AttemptRetrieval() method.

If you execute similar actions on the retrieved documents, you may consider having Contract and Assignment classes instead of ContractRetriever and AssignmentRetriever.  Then you can put common actions in their parent.

In short, a lot of the answer here lies in the unstated context of the problem.

Comment: OK.  The original question has been fleshed out since this answer.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. Originally, i didn't want to put too much in so that I could keep it as concise as possible, but it became clear that a bit of context was needed. J.

Comment: I think I'd have library as the creator of instances of LibraryDocument instances, which would be the superclass of Contract, Assignment, etc.  The Library is responsible for tracking user and file stuff (though those may turn out to be distinct responsiblitlies later), and the LibraryDocument subclasses are responsible for creating and working with individual IWorkerDocument.  The factory patterns mentioned in other posts are worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

For interested people, I have gone for a factory method.

```
public IWorkerDocument AttemptRetrieval<T>() where T : IWorkerDocument
{
    return WorkerDocument.Create<T>(fileSystem, user);
}
```

calls

```
public static IWorkerDocument Create<T>(IFileSystem fileSystem, IDocumentLibraryUser user) where T : IWorkerDocument
{
    var documentType = typeof(T);
    if (documentType == typeof(Contract))
        return new Contract(fileSystem, user);
    if (documentType == typeof(Assignment))
        return new Assignment(fileSystem, user);
    throw new Exception("Invalid Document Type");
 }
```

It's a little messy, so does anyone have any suggestions to clean the actual factory method up?

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
  public IWorkerDocument AttemptRetrieval<T>() where T:new, IWorkerDocument
     {
         return new T {FileSystem=fileSystem,User=user}
     }
```

Out of the top of my head, so may contain a blatant error ;-)

Comment: This is fine but puts the obligation on the client to know what kind of Worker they are making. It's quite likely we end up with some kind of switch statement in the client.

Comment: The Contract and Assignment classes only use the input parameters to construct themselves, they don't hold them as part of state. Should have been more clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the Abstract Factory pattern?  The declared intent in 'Design Patterns' is "Provide an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory